# How to title type in json?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, mapping

i have problem creating mapping for this json.

> Error : (MapperParsingException[failed to parse]).

However it works when you delete the `at0000` and `at0001`....(ones without a type) it works. I need to title my types somehow other than description i use it for index name. I added mapping method.Thanks for your answer and i also apologize for my english.

title for example:

```
"title":"at0000"{
       "title":"at0001"{
              "at0004":{
                "type":"String",
                "isRequired":"false"......
```

This is my mapping method:

```
public static void createMapping(){
  Logger.getLogger("Elastic Search creating mapping with contents: " + properities);
  PutMappingRequest putMapping=new PutMappingRequest(description);
  putMapping.type(name).source(properities);
  client.admin().indices().putMapping(putMapping).actionGet();
}
```

Comment: that example is not json, thats why you cannot parse it. where is this content coming from?

Comment: This part is only an example of part of json. This is how it looks like (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5rIzttAdl5fWkJqYWlrRkVUak0/view?usp=sharing). It can not parse at0000 because it doesnt have a type. Content is from openEHR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is very simple. You can just add "type":"object"